# Kafka Ktable joins Internal topic LAG got increase

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams Application version - 2.5.1 (kafka spring) and CDC connectors which continuously produce the data on the topic. I have a total of 14 topics that join the data like below and produce the result on the final topic

`ktable1.join(ktable2).leftJoin(ktable3).leftJoin(ktable4).to(finalTopic)`

When load increase on the Kafka topic it causes to increase the LAG on the internal topic lag as well and we end up with the performance delay.

did anyone know why Kafka's internal lag goes up?

- topic count = 14
- Partition count = 16*14 = 224
- Total broker = 6
- Replica factor = 2
- Number of application instance = 2

Comment: Are you aware of [KAFKA-10134](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10134)? You should consider upgrading your Kafka Streams version.

Comment: @KarstenSchnitter Thanks for the replay I have identified the issue. Actually, We have added a log statement to print each record, which caused the delay.
`peek((aLong, value) ->
                        log.info("model print")`
I have updated my version to 2.8.1 to avoid the performance.